# How to disable marketing notifications within the Magento 2 Admin Panel?

Tags: magento2

How do I stop getting these types of notifications?

Are you set up to achieve your eCommerce goals? Make upgrading your resolution for 2020.
Upgrading to Magento Commerce might cost less than you think. Watch our webinar to learn the true cost savings of upgrading to Magento Commerce 2. Watch Now: (removed bitly link)

Jan 2, 2020, 12:26:08 PM

Answer (score -1):

In general you need to disable Admin notification module.

**Admin alternative :** (2.1 -) 
you need to go to Magento 2 Admin Panel > Choose Stores

Next in the setting > select configuration

In the configuration > choose advanced > Advanced

Then you will see “Disable Modules Output” > *Magento_AdminNotification* > Choose *Disable*

Save configuration

Clear cache by going to ” cache management”

**Cli alternative :** (valid 2.x)

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminNotification
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

You're Done :)

Comment: That doesn't work in Magento 2.2+.

Comment: He didn't mention any version... So this is a valid answer

Comment: He mentioned Magento 2 in the tags. Misspelled, but still there.

Comment: Magento2 and not magento 2.2+ so still not convincing